# Stripe Publishable Key Set but Invalid (Django on Heroku)

Tags: javascript, django, heroku, stripe-payments

On the surface this setup seems straightforward but when I attempt to execute a test transaction on my staging server I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: You did not set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key.
```

Slightly perplexed by this because I *think* I am. On the template I've got:

```
<form action="" class="form" method="POST" data-stripe-key="{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}" data-replace-closest=".subscribe-form" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.stripe_token }}
            {{ form.plan }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn"><span>Sign Up</span>
            </button>

</form>
```

Below that on same template is my .js:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          Stripe.setPublishableKey('{{ my_pk }}');
        </script>
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('body').on("click", '.change-card, button[type=submit]', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $form = $(this).closest("form"),
                        token = function(res) {                        
                            $form.find("input[name=stripe_token]").val(res.id);
                            $form.trigger("submit");
                        };

                    StripeCheckout.open({
                        key:         $form.data("stripe-key"),
                        currency:    "usd", 
                        name:        'Subscription plan',
                        panelLabel:  'Subscribe',
                        token:       token
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

in settings.py I just have

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = '{{ my_pk }}'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = '{{ my_sk }}'
```

on heroku environment variables were set as

```
heroku config:add STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=my_pk STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=my_sk --remote staging
```

I've tried hardcoding the pk in the javascript, I've tried passing it in as STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY, either way I'm getting "did not set publishable key" in console.  Is there something about the Heroku environment that's causing this? do I have a .js syntax error somewhere? thanks

Comment: Do a `console.log('{{ my_pk }}');` in your JS, do you see your correct  key?

Comment: thanks. looks like setting key in StripeCheckout.open to "$form.data("stripe-key")" was my mistake --> by changing to {{ my_pk }} got it working